# Looping column values through header

Tags: python, loops, cell, rows, openpyxl

I have a column on the left side with random dates, and a header line with dates (calendar).

I am trying to loop the column values and for each value to look in the header values, once the value A is found in the header I would like to print the coordinates of Value A found in the header.

```
        01.01.2019 | 02.01.2019 | 03.01.2019 |.... | 02.02.2019 |
```

01.01.2019
02.02.2019
15.02.2019

The code should pick 01.01.2019 (column left) and loop through the header dates. Once it finds the 01.01.2019 correspondent, it should print the header coordinate (B1). And so on for the remaining dates 02.02 and 15.02.

I've tried to loop with for ws.rows, and ws.iter_cols.

```
**for row in ws.rows:
 if row[1].value == "28.06.2019":
      print("Found it vertically, value is:", row[1].value)
      #for cell in row:
      #    print(cell.value, end=" ")
      print("Vertical Value:", row[1].value, "Coordinates:", row[1].coordinate)
      target.append(row[1].coordinate)
      break
print("TARGET1:", target)
for col in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_col=30, max_row=2):
     for cell in col:
          if cell.value =="28.06.2019":
               print("Horizontal Value:", cell.value, "Coordinates:", cell.coordinate)
               target.append(cell.coordinate)
          else:
               break**
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you build a dictionary of the header and use this lookup. Something like the following should help.

```
header = {c.value:c.coordinate for c in ws[1]}
for cell in ws['A']:
    print("{0} maps to {1}".format(cell.coordinate, header[cell.value])
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will try.